# Scapy http_request "Failed to open URL"

Tags: python, http, httprequest, scapy, http-get

Im working on creating a Scapy script that does the three-way handshake, GET request, and then finally grabs the contents of a file via HTTP_request thats on a remote apache server, and then display it in the browser on my machine.

I've managed to get everything working except for when I try to do a HTTP Request it also returns that the file doesn't exist and then shows some random path its looking in.

This is the command ive been tinkering with thats on the scapy site that should work but doesnt:

```
load_layer("http")
http_request("10.10.10.10","/test", port=80, display=True)
```

- the permissions of the files on the remote host are 777 just for testing
- I can reach the web page via Firefox and it displays the file I'm looking for fine (this is just for testing as well)
- Tried chrome as well and same issue occurred
- information from this command comes back accurate when its without the path, but doesn't open the page either

The error below is the response I continuously get despite different versions of the command. The only difference is that the end of the URL string is different with every run.
i.e: this one is "BSVkz0.html" but the previous one was "WCU4c0.html"

> Failed to open URL"file:///tmp/scapyWCU4cO.html".
> Error when getting information for file "tmp/scapyBSVkz0.html": No such file or directory.

More info:
played around with it more and received a new error in terminal:

> 0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100 002b:err:winebrowser:wmain Failed to convert file URL to unix path

unsure if that's connected but the two machines involved are both Kali Linux

Any help is greatly appreciated!! thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you post the full error message (in your question)? Images of text are highly discouraged here.

Comment: But looking at the image, it's telling you all you need to know - it can't find the file you're telling it to look at.

Comment: that picture is the error message ive been getting, nothing goes wrong in terminal and executes as it should. Just the http_request produces the issue

Comment: The "display=True" option tries to download and launch the http request within your browser. It appears the browser can't open it. Could be a scapy bug, you could try reporting that on github.